# Append multiple list in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to append multiple list during list comprehension?
For example: Below works fine:

```
X = []
Y = []
[X.append(i) for i in range(100000)]
```

But, this won't even run:

```
[X.append(i), Y.append(i**2 + 3*i) for i in range(100000)]
```

How to make above work?

Comment: Why would you use a list comprehension here? It doesn't make sense. Don't use list comprehensions for side effects.

Comment: **Do not use a list comprhensions for side-effects**. Never do `[X.append(i) for i in range(100000)]
`

Comment: ```[(X.append(i), Y.append(i**2 + 3*i)) for i in range(100000)]```
?

Answer (score 2):

You should never write the code you've written above.

`[X.append(i) for i in range(...)]` generates the result `[None, None, None, ......]` where there are 100,000 `None`s in that list, and then throws it away.  It just so happens that `X.append(i)` has a side affect that you're taking advantage of.

You're looking for

`X.extend(i for i in range(100000))`

And as for the code you're trying to write.  Just make it two lines of code.  Your readers will thank you.

Or alternatively, just `X = [i for i in range(100000)]` and likewise for `Y`.

Comment: `X = list(range(100000))` is sufficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

Direcly define your list with comprehension:

```
Y = [i**2 + 3*i for i in range(1000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip(*...)` (transposing operation) to assign to different variables:

```py
X, Y = map(list, zip(*((i, i ** 2 + 3 * i) for i in range(10))))

print(X)
print(Y)
```

Prints:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 4, 10, 18, 28, 40, 54, 70, 88, 108]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to wrap your two parameters in brackets to be able to do that from within list comprehension:

```
[(X.append(i), Y.append(i**2 + 3*i)) for i in range(100000)]
```

However, doing it this way is unpythonic as it will result in a list filled with None of length 10_000 which immediately gets discarded. Just use a for loop:

```
for i in range(10_000):
  X.append(i)
  Y.append(i**2 + 3*i)
```

or, two list comprehensions:

```
X = list(range(10_000))
Y = [i**2 for i in range(10_000)]
```